# How to divide numbers in python

Tags: python

I have 6 variables where there are unknows numbers in each. So as the numbers there are so big, I want to find the major one and next divide it for itself and for the others just to have numbers like 1 or less.

Example:

```
a1=85550 
b1=-18996 
c1=45500 
d1=-60000 
e1=74666 
f1=-35666
```

In this case a1 is the major so I must divide it for it self to have 1 and for the rest to have a 0 decimal one..

I have tried this but some values are 0 so its wrong.

```
if abs(a1>b1) and abs(a1>c1) and abs(a1>d1) and abs(a1>e1) and abs(a1>f1):
    a11=a1/a1
    b11=b1/a1
    c11=c1/a1
    d11=d1/a1
    e11=e1/a1
    f11=f1/a1
else:
    if abs(b1>a1) and abs(b1>c1) and abs(b1>d1) and abs(b1>e1) and abs(b1>f1):
        a11=a1/b1
        b11=b1/b1
        c11=c1/b1
        d11=d1/b1
        e11=e1/b1
        f11=f1/b1
    else:
        if abs(c1>a1) and abs(c1>b1) and abs(c1>d1) and abs(c1>e1) and abs(c1>f1):
            a11=a1/c1
            b11=b1/c1
            c11=c1/c1
            d11=d1/c1
            e11=e1/c1
            f11=f1/c1
        else:
            if abs(d1>a1) and abs(d1>c1) and abs(d1>b1) and abs(d1>e1) and abs(d1>f1):
                a11=a1/d1
                b11=b1/d1
                c11=c1/d1
                d11=d1/d1
                e11=e1/d1
                f11=f1/d1
            else:
                if abs(e1>a1) and abs(e1>c1) and abs(e1>d1) and abs(e1>b1) and abs(e1>f1):
                    a11=a1/e1
                    b11=b1/e1
                    c11=c1/e1
                    d11=d1/e1
                    e11=e1/e1
                    f11=f1/e1
                else:
                    if abs(f1>a1) and abs(f1>c1) and abs(f1>d1) and abs(f1>e1) and abs(f1>b1):
                        a11=a1/f1
                        b11=b1/f1
                        c11=c1/f1
                        d11=d1/f1
                        e11=e1/f1
                        f11=f1/f1
```

Comment: Why not put these values in a list then? Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Hang on.  Are you dividing everything by the known largest number?

Comment: yes! exactly but i have some troubles haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your values in a list:

```
values = [a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1]
```

Now the task is a simple one:

```
max_value = max(values, key=abs)
values = [v/max_value for v in values]
```

For your input, that'd give:

```
>>> a1=85550 
>>> b1=-18996 
>>> c1=45500 
>>> d1=-60000 
>>> e1=74666 
>>> f1=-35666
>>> values = [a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1]
>>> max_value = max(values, key=abs)
>>> [v/max_value for v in values]
[1.0, -0.22204558737580363, 0.5318527177089422, -0.701344243132671, 0.8727761542957335, -0.4169023962594974]
```

This assumes you are using Python 3; in Python 2, the `/` operator on integers gives integer output, so you want to use:

```
max_value = float(max(values, key=abs))
```

just to make one of the operands a floating point number. Otherwise you'll end up with `[1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1]` instead.

The rest of your code can just use the numbers in `values` with indexing:

```
>>> values[0]
1.0
```

or you can assign the values back to the original names with sequence assignment:

```
>>> a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 = values
>>> b1
-0.22204558737580363
```

but generally you want to keep your data out of your variable names.

Comment: I dontknow how to set the new values into my old variables, like: b1 now is -0.222

Comment: @user3047319: I show you how at the end of my answer. I'd use `values[1]` instead of `b1` in the rest of your code, however.

Comment: Yea but whem I do `a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 = values` after `[v/max_value for v in values]` and then print b1, it gives me the old value of the variable.

Comment: You do need to assign the output of the list comprehension first. :-) `values = [v / max_value for v in values]`.

Comment: or you can combine the two: `a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 = [v / max_value for v in values]`.

Comment: Do you know how to change the sign of the resultant numbers in a way that a1 is positive, b1 negative, c1 positive again and so?

Comment: I am not certain what you mean; you want to maintain the sign even if the absolute maximum value is negative you mean?

Comment: yes! I want to keep the sign of the denominator in the new variable, for example: if -30000/-80000 I want that the resultant number keep the sign of 80000 I mean "negative"

Comment: @user3047319: Then make the maximum value absolute: `max_value = max(float(abs(v)) for v in values)`.

Answer (score 1):

the `/` in python gives you an integer (whole number) if you are dividing integers.  if the answer isn't exact it rounds down.  so `1/2` is 0, not 0.5.

instead of

```
a / b
```

try converting one to a float:

```
a / float(b)
```

then you will get, say, 0.5 where you expect it.

you can also write a number as a float directly.  `1.0/2` will give 0.5, for example, because `1.0` is a float, not an integer.

(also, what everyone else is saying about using lists)

Answer (score 0):

to divide two numbers, `x` and `y`, use the `/` operator:

```
z = x / y
```

Comment: in python 2 you probably want `x / float(y)` or similar

Comment: @andrewcooke The question sounds like integer arithmetic is required.

Comment: "1 or less" being 1 or zero?!?!  nope.

Comment: i want to have the number 1 as the higher and then decimal numbers starting with 0 like 0,21552

Answer (score -3):

Place your values into a list.

```
l = [85550, -18996, 45500, -60000, 74666, -35666]
```

Sort the list in reverse order.

```
l.sort(reverse = True)
```

Then, `map` a function that divides each value by `l[0]`, or the largest known value.

```
result = map(lambda x: x / l[0], l)
```

The answer will be every value in the list divided as integers by the max value, including the max value.

```
[1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1]
```

If integer division is undesirable, cast x to a float.

```
result = map(lambda x: x / l[0], l)

[1.0, 0.8727761542957335, 0.5318527177089422, -0.22204558737580363, -0.4169023962594974, -0.701344243132671]
```

**Alternative:**  Instead of sorting the list, only write the mapping function to go across `x / max(l)`.

```
result = map(lambda x: x / max(l), l)
```

Comment: Why sort the list when `max()` will tell you the largest number for you? Note that the the OP is finding the largest *absolute* number.

Comment: And what if order was important? You now sorted the values, so the OP is not going to be able to sort out what number was `b1` from `e1`.

Comment: Another nitpick: your alternative not only does not find the absolute maximum value, it also needlessly recalculates the maximum for every element in `l`. At the very least move that out. The line where you say the OP should cast `x` to a float doesn't actually do so, you show the exact same code that produced the integer results.